# How can you copy the subset of a DataFrame in another .py archive?

Tags: python, dataframe, copy, subset

I have been using a `Salary.csv` archive from a DataCamp course and I want to copy a subset of it to show it on StackOverflow but I´m not able to do it as it is stored as a DataFrame, and I would have to quit the indexes manually and be writing the commas too.

I know that one way is to use `str.replace()`(or I suppose that) but I´m not sure how to do it as there are spaces between values and seems complicated.

I have created an example for this. Let´s say that I select a subset based on the low median:

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import random
# Howdo we know the number of executives?
random.seed(3)
num_entries = 100
salaries = [random.randint(0,100000) for  x in range(num_entries)]

#Mapping salaries to salary_levels:
def map_salary_level(salary):
    if salary <= 25000:
        return "Entry"
    elif salary <= 50000:
        return "Mid"
    elif salary <= 75000:
        return "Senior"
    else:
        return "Executive"

salary_levels = [map_salary_level(salary) for salary in salaries]

data = {"Salary_USD": salaries, "Salary_Level": salary_levels}
salaries_df = pd.DataFrame(data)

salaries_median = salaries_df["Salary_USD"].quantile(0.5)

low50_salaries = salaries_df[["Salary_USD","Salary_Level"]].loc[salaries_df["Salary_USD"] <= salaries_median]
# 2. How do I paste this values in another .py archive to create a new df?
print(low50_salaries)
```

My question is, is there any way to copy or carry the content of the subset `low50_salaries` to create a new DataFrame in another `.py` archive?

Answer (score 0):

Why not doing:

- At the end of your actual code: `low50_salaries.to_csv("low50_salaries.csv", index=False)`
- in your other .py: `df_low50 = read_csv("low50_salaries.csv")`

You could also import the variable but it depends of your project context too

Comment: Well the problem with that is that if I want to upload the dataset on StackOverflow I cannot show it as you don´t have the .csv, the point is, is there any way to copy it with the print statement + (ctrl + c) and some code?

Comment: ok I understand better. Have you tried the `df.to_clipboard()` function ?